# Bodhi Issue with Nautilus as SU

Tags: sudo, nautilus, bodhi

I am unsure how to run Nautilus with superuser privilieges on Bodhi, or if this is just a bad idea altogether. I am looking for a file manager that can browse my local network, and can be run as superuser. Nautilus works in these respects, but has side-effects. If I need to make adjustments, and want to browse my network, what can I be doing better?

When I run `sudo nautilus` I get a big blue window covering my desktop and the following output in LXTerminal:

```
(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:81:18: Horizontal and vertical offsets are required

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:111:23: Horizontal and vertical offsets are required

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:117:23: Horizontal and vertical offsets are required

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:121:23: Horizontal and vertical offsets are required

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:127:23: Horizontal and vertical offsets are required

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:134:23: Horizontal and vertical offsets are required

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:141:23: Horizontal and vertical offsets are required

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:145:23: Horizontal and vertical offsets are required

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:156:23: Horizontal and vertical offsets are required

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:163:23: Horizontal and vertical offsets are required

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:170:23: Horizontal and vertical offsets are required

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:177:23: Horizontal and vertical offsets are required

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:186:23: Horizontal and vertical offsets are required

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:196:23: Horizontal and vertical offsets are required

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gnome-applications.css:87:24: 'px' is not a valid color name

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gnome-applications.css:108:18: Horizontal and vertical offsets are required

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: granite-widgets.css:167:28: 'px' is not a valid color name

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: lightdm-gtk-greeter.css:18:23: Horizontal and vertical offsets are required

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: lightdm-gtk-greeter.css:38:23: Horizontal and vertical offsets are required

(nautilus:3690): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: lightdm-gtk-greeter.css:57:23: Horizontal and vertical offsets are required

** (nautilus:3690): WARNING **: Can not calculate _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS

** (nautilus:3690): WARNING **: Can not calculate _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS

** (nautilus:3690): WARNING **: Can not get _NET_WORKAREA

** (nautilus:3690): WARNING **: Can not determine workarea, guessing at layout
```

Comment: Does `sudo nautilus --no-desktop` makes any difference?

Comment: @MartínCanaval `--no-=desktop` doesn't bring up the blue desktop window, but the Gtk-wanings still flood LXD; is this something to be concerned about or that can be corrected?

Comment: All the errors on *.css files are related to gtk3 themes, they are (as far as I know) harmless.